# File system for carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, carrierwave

I have been looking at [carrier wave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for image uploading for a website I am creating. I have heard good things about carrier wave and same with paper clip.

What I can't seem to find information on is how either gem handles its file system. Do you I need to get a plugin to make a fast query-able file system? Were these gems(specifically carrier wave) desgined to handle a large amount of users posting pictures and if so how do they save the files?

One option that I will probably use is severin's answer at the very bottom of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460686/carrierwave-file-hash-and-model-id-in-filename-store-dir).

However if these gems already have a good file system implemented then there isn't a point in over complicating things, just need some input from you guys on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Paperclip with Rails 2 and switched to Carrierwave when migrated to Rails 3.

Both of these solutions write the files to the public folder with a similar folder structure.

Carrierwave also has another nice gem "Carrierwave direct" which allows to upload to a remote server or S3 directly from the user browser, which is nice for scaling. It is also a requirement when using Heroku which doesn't have a file system (or didn't have one available prviously)

Comment: Do these photos just get placed into the public fold with no organization? Or can it handle a large user base for uploading photos. Example: I get 10,000 users posting photos, do all the photos get placed into one folder or does Carrierwave create a traversable file system.

Comment: Usually the Files are attached to an uploader so the files are stored under the assets/:id ... but this can be configured the way you want.

Comment: But if you upload a massive amount of photos, you might want to go with a :fog solution, where the photos are uploaded to S3, Rackspace or other. All this is supported by carrierwave