# How Do I get the class to which the current class belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have an uploader (carrierewave) to save several files, but I'm afraid that some days, some files will have the same name and will cause a problem. Moreover, I'd want the folders to keep a semblance of organization.

So, I have a first scaffold, "magazine" that allows me to create a magazine with its title and several images. The second scaffold that I use, "page", allows the multi upload system.

With this method, my models look like this:

**magazine.rb**

```
has_many :pages, :inverse_of => :magazine, :dependent => :destroy
```

**pages.rb**

```
belongs_to :magazine
```

Now in my uploader, I have the following:

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
  end
```

which creates folders like this : "uploads / page / image", then uploads every single images inside it, even thought if it's for an other magazine, so the images get mixed up.

My question is the following: is there a way to get to write the magazine's ID instead ? This implies to find the class "pages" belongs to, but I didn't find anything answering my question on google.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom uploader mounted in the model `Page` you could access the model attributes normally

**PageImageUploader.rb**

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/magazines/#{model.magazine.id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

However, you can't access the models IDs unless your models are persisted. A workaround for that can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468007/6227336).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked even better than I thought!