# NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass): in CarrierWave model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload images in my rails project. This is my `uploader` class.

```
class ProfilePictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

I am **not** using `mount_uploader :avatar , ProfilePictureUploader` in my `model`. Instead I use this in my model

```
uploader = ProfilePictureUploader.new
uploader.store!(file)
self.image = uploader.url
self.save
```

But this is giving me an error saying

> NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)

Understandably the `model` instance is not available in `ProfilePictureUploader`. So `store_dir` method can't access `model.id`.  How can I get a similar directory structure with this flow.

This is not a duplicate of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460686/carrierwave-file-hash-and-model-id-in-filename-store-dir) . For me , the `model` attribute of `uploader` is not available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carrierwave: file hash and model id in filename/store\_dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460686/carrierwave-file-hash-and-model-id-in-filename-store-dir)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460686/carrierwave-file-hash-and-model-id-in-filename-store-dir . For me , the model attribute of uploader is not available.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should properly initialize your uploader with your model instance:

```
mounted_as = "profile-or-something-else"
uploader = ProfilePictureUploader.new(self, mounted_as)
uploader.store!(file)
self.image = uploader.url
self.save
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks man. That worked. Can you tell me what ``mounted_as`` attribute stands for? Any documentation on this?

Comment: Usually it's name of column of your model. Ex.: `mount_uploader :avatar , ProfilePictureUploader` here :avatar is mounted_as. Details https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/c45699c318ca895f89fa3304204e48b5f1c411f1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/mountable.rb